# Enhancing computation speed of Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to develop a basic R shiny app but facing issues with the processing speed. The procedure is as follows, I need to read csv file of about 500K rows -> split the file into smaller segments -> calculate new features for each segment and display the result. Below are my `UI.R` and `Server.R`
`UI.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(DT)


shinyUI(fluidPage( 
mainPanel(
#UI for choosing the file to input
fileInput("file1", label = (" Choose Drivecycle Data "),multiple = F),

#UI for showing the number of Rows in original dataset 
fluidRow(
  column(8, h4(helpText("Number of rows input dataset"))),
  column(3,verbatimTextOutput("totrows", placeholder = TRUE))),

#UI for showing the number of segments the data set had been split into
fluidRow(
  column(8, h4(helpText("Number of segmentations"))),
  column(3,verbatimTextOutput("totseg", placeholder = TRUE))),

fluidRow(
  column(8, downloadButton("subtablednld", label = 'Downloadcsv'))
),

tabsetPanel(

  #UI to show the original data set in First tab
  tabPanel("Table",icon = icon("table"),withSpinner(DT::dataTableOutput('table'), 
                                                    type = getOption("spinner.type", default = 8) )),

  #UI to show the  features of the segments of the orginal dataset in Second Tab
  tabPanel("Feature Table",icon = icon("table"),withSpinner(DT::dataTableOutput('table1'), 
                                                            type = getOption("spinner.type", default = 8) )),


),style = 'width:1000px;height"3000px'
)
)
)
```

`Server.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(earth)
library(tidyr)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=300*1024^2) #increase the max upload file size 
to 30 MB
options(shiny.trace=TRUE)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

#Function to input data set using UI 
dataframe <- reactive( {

###  Create a data frame reading data file to be used by other functions..
inFile <- input$file1

data1 <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)

 })

 #Display the input dataset
 observeEvent(input$file1,output$table <- renderDataTable({dataframe()}))

 #Show the number of rows in the input dataset
 observeEvent(input$file1,output$totrows<- renderText({nrow(dataframe())}))

 #Split the data set
 Splitfile <- function(){
 split(dataframe(), (seq(nrow(dataframe()))-1) %/% 200)
 }

 #Show the number of segments the data has been split into
 observeEvent(input$file1,output$totseg <-renderText({length(Splitfile())}))

  #Acceleration calculation function
  Acceleration <- function(){
  c <- lapply(1:length(Splitfile()), function(i)
  {

   acceleration <- c(0,diff(Splitfile()[[i]]$Vehicle.Speed)/2)


    })
 Splitfile <- mapply(cbind, Splitfile(), "acceleration" = c, SIMPLIFY = F)
 Splitfile
 }

 #Calculating Features 

  CaclFeatures <- function(){  
  FileFeatures <- lapply(1:length(Acceleration()), function(i){

   Velocity_mean <-round(mean(Acceleration()[[i]]$Vehicle.Speed),digits = 3)

   Variance_Velocity      <-round(var(Acceleration()[[i]]$Vehicle.Speed)*
                                    ((length(Acceleration( 
                               [[i]]$Vehicle.Speed)-1)/length(Acceleration() 
                               [[i]]$Vehicle.Speed))
                                   ,digits = 3)

      c(Velocity_mean,
        Variance_Velocity)

    })
     FileFeatures<- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, FileFeatures))
     names(FileFeatures)[names(FileFeatures) == 'V1'] <- "Velocity_Mean"
     names(FileFeatures)[names(FileFeatures) == 'V2'] <- "Variance_Velocity"
    }

    #Display the table containing all features of all the segments
      output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
         CaclFeatures()},options = list(scrollX = TRUE))


    #Print to csv
       output$subtablednld <- downloadHandler(

         filename = function(){

              paste("dataset-", ".csv", sep = "")
           },

       content = function(file){

      write.csv(CaclFeatures(), file ,row.names = FALSE)
        }
         )

      })
```

The app works fine if I read csv file of about `2k` rows but does not work if I read data set more than `2k`, It will neither give any error nor crash. The spinner keeps rotating but fails to show the result. Also, the same logic when used in regular `R script` work fine with large data set of more than `500k`, rather I'm calculating `22` new features.
Currently, I am using a system of `8gb RAM` `i5 Processor`. Is there a way to enhance the computing speed, when checked within my task manager `Rstudio` uses only around `47% - 52%` of memory, I have no other process running other than `R studio`

*EDIT*: Sample data can be created by using the code below,
         `drive <- as.data.frame(sample(1:50, 500000, replace = T))`

Comment: Please don't provide a link to google drive for data; when (not if) the link goes stale, this question will be completely unreproducible. Instead, I suggest you provide a completely self-contained reproducible question, including representative data in the question (perhaps using `dput(head(x,n=20))` or similar).

Comment: @r2evans okay, I will remove the link and provide sample data.

Comment: `read.csv` is notoriously slow. try `fread` instead, for starters

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks for the suggestion, I tried with `fread` but didn't work, Problem is not with reading the file but in the calculation of `features`.

Comment: You maybe need to profile your code to know exactly where time is spent and concentrate on that part. From your code it seems you compute twice (in renderDataTable and write.csv) your feature but maybe it's part of your debug code

Comment: I don't understand also how you are computing your data. It seems you are mixing reactive values (your dataframe()) and compute functions (Splitfile(), acceleration()) resulting in multiple evaluations of same data with same parameters giving same results but at the cost of additional time! reactive values are cached, not your functions

Comment: Please provide useful sample data. Your code is expecting at least Vehicle.Speed. There is also dangerous code construction (using c as variable, redefining Splitfile function in Acceleration) and various design flaws. I know it does not help but I think it's more an R code problem than a Shiny problem. For the Splitfile and acceleration function you should use reactive (ex Splitfile <- reactive({your code}) )

Comment: @Learner `fread` is part of the `data.table` package. You'll have to install that to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole calculation seems to be dependent on some structural properties from your input data.frame, so I can't produce a working example in a reasonable time, with only minor changes to your code.

**BUT**, your code evaluation is aweful performance wise.

Take `Acceleration` for example. **WITHIN** your `lapply`, you call `Splitfile()`, which is a **regular function**. Assume that the number of splits is about 2500, you call this function **2500 times**. And the operation `split(dataframe(), (seq(nrow(dataframe()))-1) %/% 200)` takes about 2 seconds on my computer, so you're waiting 5000 seconds, while the result of `Splitfiles()` is always the same. And then, inside `CalcFeatures`, you call `Acceleration()` again four times inside each `lapply` loop. That makes for an approximate waiting time of 5 000 * 2 500 * 4 = 50 000 000 seconds or 578 days.

You might have been confused with the concept of `reactive` where the function call would just return the current value and reevaluation is implicit.

So you either:

1. Call expensive functions once at the beginning of your function.

   - Start `Acceleration` with `files <- Splitfiles()` and use `files` from there on.
   - Start `CalcFeatures` with `acc <- Acceleration()` and use `acc` from there on.
2. Turn your functions into reactives.

   - `Splitfiles <- reactive({ ... dataframe() ... })`
   - `Acceleration <- reactive({ ... Splitfiles() ... })`
   - `CalcFeature <- reactive({ ... Acceleration() ... })`

A mixture of both concepts is not better. Stick to either one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I tried with turning functions into reactives. Now it is working as expected.